# How to read user command input and store parts in variables

Tags: python, discord.py

So let's say that user types `!give_money user#5435 33000`

Now I want to take that `user#5435` and `33000` and store them in variables.

How do I do that? Maybe it is very simple but I don't know.

If you need any more info please comment.

Thanks!

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python input user", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: @Joe Iddon explained it great already but thanks!

Comment: You tagged this [tag:discord.py], are you looking for a way to get these values from a discord command?

Comment: Yes, but I managed to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the input on spaces and extract the second and third elements:

```
parts = input().split()
user = parts[1]
numb = parts[2]
```

Although it would be more Pythonic to unpack into variables (discarding the first with a conventional underscore):

```
_, user, numb = input().split()
```

---

Just to elaborate further, `input.split()` returns a list of the sublists split at the deliminator passed into the function. However, when there are no inputs, the string is split on spaces.

To get a feel, observe:

```
>>> 'hello there bob'.split()
['hello', 'there', 'bob']
>>> 'split,on,commas'.split(',')
['split', 'on', 'commas']
```

and then unpacking just assigns variables to each element in a list:

```
>>> a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list_of_sub_string=YourString.split()
print(list_of_sub_string[-1])  #33000
print(list_of_sub_string[-2])  #user#5435
```

Comment: why index backwards? :p guess it still works though so +1